# vline group chat issue

Tags: video, webrtc, videochat, vline

I have setup one to one chat which is provided by Vline for PHP and that working fine. However, when I try to deploy group chat there is some issue. Group chat is not working.

I have tried using the Vline group chat PHP API but I'm not understanding how to set it up. Please can you send me running example of it? I already configured one to one chat of Vline please help me with that issue

What is remote user?
How to set up group chat?

Answer (score 0):

We currently don't support group chat, but it's on our feature list. Feel free to vote for it (and any other features you'd like to see) on our [UserVoice page](http://vline.uservoice.com/forums/183120-general/suggestions/3389731-group-chat-and-video).